# Different AUC-PR scores using Logistic Regression with and without Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, auc, average-precision, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'm trying to understand why I get different AUC-PR scores using Logistic Regression with and without Pipeline.

Here is my code **with** using Pipeline:

```
column_encoder = ColumnTransformer([
    ('ordinal_enc', OrdinalEncoder(), categorical_cols)
])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('column_encoder', column_enc),
    ('logreg', LogisticRegressionCV(random_state=777))
])

model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(f'AUC-PR with Pipeline: {average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred):.4f}')
```

And here is my code **without** Pipeline:

```
ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder()
ord_encoded_X_train = ord_enc.fit_transform(X_train[categorical_cols])
ord_encoded_X_test = ord_enc.transform(X_test[categorical_cols])

X_train_encoded = X_train.copy(deep=True)
X_test_encoded = X_test.copy(deep=True)

X_train_encoded.loc[:, categorical_cols] = copy.deepcopy(ord_encoded_X_train)
X_test_encoded.loc[:, categorical_cols] = copy.deepcopy(ord_encoded_X_test)

model = LogisticRegression(random_state=777, max_iter=2000)
model.fit(X_train_encoded, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_encoded)

print(f'AUC-PR without Pipeline: {average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred):.4f}')
```

And finally:

```
AUC-PR with Pipeline:    0.1133
AUC-PR without Pipeline: 0.2406
```

So, why is that?

Comment: Do Not fit_transform on test data.  Only transform, using the fitted statistics from the training set.

Comment: @BenReiniger, thank you, but that doesn't change the result. The difference still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ColumnTransformer` is dropping all the columns that aren't in `categorical_cols`, because the default for `remainder` is `"drop"`.  Add `remainder="passthrough"` to keep the non-categorical columns for the model.

Other quibbles:

- You set `max_iter` in the second approach but not the first.
- You are computing `average_precision_score` with hard class predictions, when you should use probability predictions.